# What is the benefit of removing unused levels in R?

Tags: r, levels

Let's say, for example, you have levels "Car", "Truck", "Bus" for your vehicle dataset. Your data, however, only contains Car and Truck data.

Is there a benefit to removing the unused level "Bus"?

Comment: Suppose you want to get the frequency of that column that returns 0 for the "Bus",  then it should be kept.  Otherwise, it can be removed.

Comment: It really depends on what it is you are trying to achieve. If there is no data for a particular category, and you don't need to / want to summarize, model or display that fact, then remove. Otherwise, keep. Refactoring the levels is very useful, but does not necessarily have to be used all the time.

Comment: I understand that I can remove it, but why is it beneficial to do so? Does it speed up computation time?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the data you access (from a source that you cannot change) has data for Bus, Car, Truck, and Trck. You re-code the Trck value in your code, but the level "Trck" remains. This would be a situation to remove this level.